# Exception generated during rename_column migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to change a column in my sqlite DB via a migration...and I have no idea what I'm doing with RoR so please be gentle!

Here's the migration I'm trying to run.

```
class FixContactIdColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :calls, :contact, :contact_id
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

And here's the exception it's generating.

```
brad@brad-vm:~/www/contactly$ vim db/migrate/20101013020151_fix_contact_id_column.rb
brad@brad-vm:~/www/contactly$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /home/brad/www/contactly)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
==  FixContactIdColumn: migrating =============================================
-- rename_column(:calls, :contact, :contact_id)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:480:in `column'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:363:in `copy_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:357:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:357:in `copy_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:104:in `create_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:355:in `copy_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:349:in `move_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:342:in `alter_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:341:in `alter_table'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:311:in `rename_column'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
./db/migrate//20101013020151_fix_contact_id_column.rb:3:in `up_without_benchmarks'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `__send__'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:486:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:560:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:560:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:560:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:485:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:472:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:472:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:400:in `up'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
/home/brad/www/contactly/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/databases.rake:116
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

Any ideas? I would be happy to provide additional details...

**Update:** It was suggested that I try to rollback my previous migration...but I get similar results.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 brad brad  166 2010-10-12 17:21 20101013002111_add_notes_to_call.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 brad brad  175 2010-10-12 17:22 20101013002240_add_contact_to_call.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 brad brad  146 2010-10-12 19:25 20101013020151_fix_contact_id_column.rb
brad@brad-vm:~/www/contactly/db/migrate$ rake db:migrate VERSION=20101013002111
(in /home/brad/www/contactly)
==  AddContactToCall: reverting ===============================================
-- remove_column(:calls, :contact)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: is it possible that the table `calls` does not have a column `contact` ? Because that is how it seems to me.

Answer (score 1):

Though this problem should be fixed in `schema_definitions.rb`, you can get rid of this error by creating a `to_sym` instance method for `NilClass`.

Create an initializer in your rails application under `config/initializers/nil_class.rb` and add this to it:

```
class NilClass
  def to_sym
    nil
  end
end
```

After you've done this, try running your migration again.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your original migration.

If your migration isn't in the production yet, just edit your original migration to fit what you need and run:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=<migration_date>
rake db:migrate
```

the migration_date is the timestamp that is in the name of the migration file. Remember also, you must pick the migration before the one that you plan to re execute, so if you have:

```
201010101005_create_users.rb
201010101010_create_calls.rb
```

You want to run:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=201010101005
```

Comment: Hmm I tried what you suggested in got similar results. I updated my original post. Can you please provide any more direction? I *really* want to "get" RoR...

Comment: Can you paste the original migration? The one that has the create for the table.